# javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

i am new and learning ejb 3.0

MyFirstEjbApp

```
@Stateless
@RemoteBinding(jndiBinding="bean1")
public class MyFirstEjb implements MyFirstEjbRemote {


    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyFirstEjb.class);

    public MyFirstEjb() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        log.info("do something has been called");
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "get description has returned some value";
    }
}
```

EjbTestClient.java

```
public class EjbTestClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException  {
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        System.out.println("context lookup finished");

        MyFirstEjbRemote proxy  = (MyFirstEjbRemote)(context.lookup("bean1"));
        System.out.println(proxy.getClass().toString());
        System.out.println(proxy.getDescription());
        proxy.doSomething();
    }

}
```

jndi.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming.client
java.naming.factory.provider.url=localhost:1099
```

i thought firewall might be the problem and disabled it but the problems still remains.

```
context lookup finished
```

is printed on console and then after some seconds i get an error:-

```
    context lookup finished
    Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out
 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1690)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1812)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:695)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:688)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at EjbTestClient.main(EjbTestClient.java:13)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
        at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.discoverServer(NamingContext.java:1659)
        ... 5 more
```